# Use setBackgroundResource in a other method?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the following code in my onCreate-method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ImageView field1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.field1);
    field1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field0);
```

How can I set the BackgroundResource in any other method like this:

```
public void setBackground() {
    field1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field2);
}
```

It says, that field1 cannot be resolved to a variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set field1 to global of the class, as follows:

```
ImageView field1=null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    field1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.field1);
    field1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field0);

}


public void setBackground() {
    field1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the view in parameter of your function :

```
public void setBackground(ImageView view) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field2);
}
```

and now you can call it like that :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ImageView field1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.field1);
    setBackground(field1);
```

Anyway you should probably read some code tutorial in order to learn the basis of coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView field1;
```

Set ImageView on top of the onCreate Method, because it can be used by whole of your class